# my scanner stopped working after a couple of runs and gives me the java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "7642874781"

Tags: java, string, integer, java.util.scanner, inputmismatchexception

After the name, Charlie is printed out it throws the input mismatch exception and says I'm entering a string into the int scanner but it really is a number so why is it telling me it's a string?

This is my textfile that the scanner is reading from:
Alice,1234567891,Priority
Brandon,1987654321,Senior
Charlie,7642874781,Regular
Danny,5274847643,Senior

```
package file reading;

public class Customer {
    
    private String name;
    private int phoneNumber;
    private int seatNumber;
    String  classification;


    public Customer(String name, int phoneNumber, String classification) 
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.classification = classification;
    }



    public String getName() {return name;}
    public int getPhoneNumber() {return phoneNumber;}
    public int getSeatNumber() {return seatNumber;}
    public String getClassification() {return classification;}


    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
    public void setPhoneNumber(int phoneNumber) {this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;}
    public void setSeatNumber(int seatNumber) {this.seatNumber = seatNumber;}
    public void setClassification(String classification) {this.classification = classification;}


    public String toString()
    {
        return "Name: " + name + "\nPhone Number: " + phoneNumber +
        "   \nclassification: "  + classification +"\n";
    }
    
}



package file reading;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class URLDissector
{
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Reads customer info from a file and prints their path components.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
      String customerInfo;
      Scanner fileScan, infoScan;
      String name = "", classification = "";
      int phoneNumber = 0 ,seatNumber = 0;
   
      
      try {     
          fileScan = new Scanner(new File("info.txt"));

          while (fileScan.hasNext())
          {
             customerInfo = fileScan.nextLine();
             System.out.println("Customer: " + customerInfo);
    
             infoScan = new Scanner(customerInfo);
             infoScan.useDelimiter(",");
    
             //  Print each part of the customer info
             while (infoScan.hasNext()) {
                 name = infoScan.next();
                 //The error is hapening right here, right after printing out the name Charlie it won't 
                 //print the phone number and stops everything.
                 phoneNumber = infoScan.nextInt();
                 
                 classification = infoScan.next();

                 
                 Customer customer = new Customer(name, phoneNumber, classification);
                 System.out.println("Customer " + customer);
             }
                
    
             System.out.println();
          }
      }catch (FileNotFoundException f){
          System.out.println ("File not found");
      }
   }
```

Thank you for reading my question!

Comment: What is max value of `int`? How is it compared to 7_642_874_781?

Comment: @Pshemo Thank you for reminding me of this! the number for Charlie and Danny were too big for an int value. That was a simple fix thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

In Java, the `integer` datatype is `32-bit` which has the maximum value of `2,147,483,647` but your input string is "7642874781" which will be converted to `7,642,874,781`. That exceeds the maximum value of an integer data type, which causes the error.

Consider using `long` datatype with the method `nextLong()` of the scanner object.